# Can puppeteer run on Render.com?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, render.com

I've trying to deploy puppeteer on Render.com,
I can do other requests but puppeteer does not seem to work,
did I do something wrong

```
async function startBrowser() {
  let browser;
  try {
    console.log("Opening the browser......");
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
      args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--use-gl=egl",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      ],
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not create a browser instance => : ", err);
  }
  return browser;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling and using this function? As it is now, it doesn't appear that you've done anything with the `browser` instance. There is also debug options for puppeteer to not run in headless mode, so you can see the browser instance it is manipulating in real time

Comment: if your code is behaving as intended (see the comment of Rogue), you will be able to run puppeteer on Render instances, yes. even on the free tier (but it will be slower compared to free Heroku dynos for example).

Comment: I used to scrap some news, it's run locally fine but when I deploy it in Render.com it seems not working

Comment: I also tried in headless: true and headless: 'chrome' but it still not working

Comment: You want `headless: false`, headless mode runs without showing the browser.

Comment: I mean my project works fine locally but when I deploy it doesn't, no matter what mode of headless is. And when I try to access the API it always returns requesttimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I forgot to switch back to `headless : true`, and in `headless : true` I have to set user agent for that page. Example:
`await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36")`