# Puppeteer not working in Render Production environment

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, render

Here's my code:

```
async function getReadableContent(url) {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            // Navigate to the URL
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

            // Extract HTML content
            const pageContent = await page.content();
            var doc = new JSDOM(pageContent, { url });

            // Use Readability to parse the content
            const article = new Readability(doc.window.document).parse();

            await browser.close();

            return article ? article.textContent : null;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching and extracting content:', error.message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This code works fine in local environment, but in production, I get this:

Error fetching and extracting content: Could not find Chrome (ver. 122.0.6261.69). This can occur if either  you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or  your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /opt/render/.cache/puppeteer). For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.

Can anyone help figure this out?  I have tried adding npx puppeteer browsers install chrome in deploy command, made no difference.

Comment: Did you see https://docs.render.com/deploy-puppeteer-node and [Can puppeteer run on Render.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028987/can-puppeteer-run-on-render-com)

Comment: Checked this but these didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is a dependency issue. Install puppetter dependencies before running this on your production.

Comment: I did npm install puppeteer@latest --save, and deployed. But this did not make any difference. Am i missing something?

Comment: This is the worst part of puppeteer. When you deploy the app Chrome does not exist. You have to install it. I am trying my heart out using Docker but its seemingly impossible. I dont know how anyone has deployed puppeteer.