# Puppeteer deploy error on Render: Error: Could not find Chrome

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, puppeteer

I have an application that after deployment stops working to generate a PDF from an API created, it presents this error in the console (Render) when I try to generate the PDF.

As this is a project application hosted on GitHub pages, could anyone help me solve this problem?

I would like to add this application to my projects.

```
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 121.0.6167.85). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /opt/render/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:285:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:196:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:89:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:70:28)
    at async /opt/render/project/src/routes/bill.js:48:21
```

I tried some solutions searching for this error on ChatGPT but without success.

Comment: Did you try running `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome` or checking that the cache path is correctly configured, as the error suggests? There is  also a [GH issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9694) and [Can puppeteer run on Render.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028987/can-puppeteer-run-on-render-com). Please also share a [mcve] of your code. It's difficult to debug what can't be seen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can puppeteer run on Render.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74028987/can-puppeteer-run-on-render-com)